# Is it possible to write a code which can give me the XPath for a particular element?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My concern is that whether is it possible to generate a XPath dynamically just by choosing an element, so that I don't have to worry about the updates which take place in HTML files periodically for any website.
Feel free to leave any thought which can work as an alternative for this problem where I don't have to generate XPath manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I wrote code for exactly this issue.

My situation was: I needed to check elements located somewhere on a page, but the XPath changed from time to time. As all elements were in a table, only thing I needed to know was the XPath of the first element and then check every other row to see if other elements were present.

I used

```
        public void UserGetsXPathOfElement(string element){
        string PageSource = Driver.PageSource;
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(PageSource);

        var decs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList();
        var targetEl = decs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.InnerText.Trim() == element && c.Name == "td");
        var newXpath = targetEl.XPath;

        var regex = new Regex(@"tr\[\d+\]");
        newXpath = regex.Replace(newXpath, @"tr[{0}]");

        ScenarioContext.Current["xpath"] = newXpath;
    }
```

Only in this piece of code, I send a variable XPath var in ScenarioContext and I also trim my xpath to till the td. You can leave this out of course.